# Lifetime of a std::initializer list global/static object

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, lifetime

The `std::initializer_list` is mostly used as class constructors/functions argument in order to copy the list elements into another container. But what about creating a global object using `std::initializer_list`? E.g.:

```
struct ElemType {
    const char* name;
    bool        flag;
};

std::initializer_list<ElemType> MyGlobalData = { {"One",true}, {"Two",false} };
```

If to look at the `std::initializer_list` template definition (checked in Visual Studio 2017), it contains only 2 data members: `const _Elem *_First` and `_Last`.
It means that the initializer list data should be stored in an automatic variable. **What is its lifetime in this case?**

Such example tested in Visual Studio 2017 looks working good. But I doubt whether this behaviour corresponds to the latest C++ standard.

Comment: Whats the concern? The initializer list holds whatever you put in it. So, if you place a pointer in it, it won't be responsible for managing what the pointer points to. On the other hand the tiny amount of memory that the pointer occupies (size_t) will be managed as any other variable.

Comment: @Mikhail this is not obvious. See [`[initializer_list.syn]`](http://eel.is/c++draft/initializer_list.syn).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's well defined.

> **[dcl.init.list]/5** An object of type `std::initializer_list<E>` is constructed from an initializer list as if the implementation generated and materialized (7.4) a prvalue of type "array of `N` `const E`", where `N` is the number of elements in the initializer list.
>
> **[dcl.init.list]/6** The array has the same lifetime as any other temporary object (15.2), except that initializing an `initializer_list` object from the array **extends the lifetime** of the array exactly like binding a reference to a temporary.

Emphasis mine.

Comment: I was missing /6, shame on me. +1

Comment: Only that we are not initializing it from array, we are initializing it from another initializer list

Comment: @SergeyA: It is being initialized from a braced-init-list, not an `initializer_list`.

Comment: @SergeyA "The array" in /6 refers to the "prvalue of type array" mentioned in /5

Comment: @SergeyA: You're misunderstanding something. It's not creating an `initalizer_list` and then copying it into the `initializer_list` it is going to store. It is creating the `initializer_list` in the global object, initialized from the temporary array. When you use a braced-init-list to initialize an object, there's no "create and copy" nonsense.

Comment: @Igor, you could quote the example of /6: "For [`std::initializer_list<int> i3 = { 1, 2, 3 };`], the initializer_­list object is a variable, so the array persists for the lifetime of the variable."

Comment: @NicolBolas I guess so. It is list-initializing initializer list, alright.

Comment: @SergeyA: It would have been more problematic in pre c++17: `auto MyGlobalData = std::initializer_list<ElemType>{ {"One",true}, {"Two",false} };` :-/

Comment: What happens if the initializer_list is a data member of an aggregate that you initialize at namespace scope? Does lifetime extension appy? I suppose so?